# Images only update after scrolling UITableView

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview, lazy-loading

I have a horizontal scrolling table view. Each cell takes the whole screen to show full pictures. I'm doing lazy loading of the pictures. The problem I'm having is that when the pictures finish downloading, the UIImageview.image from the cell is not updated automatically. I need to scroll to another cell and back for it to show.
Here is the method called when the picture is finished downloading:

```
    - (void)imageDownloaderDidFinish:(PictureDownloadOperation *)downloader {
           NSLog(@"image download finished");
           NSIndexPath *indexPath = downloader.indexPathInTableView;
           PictureRecord *theRecord = downloader.photoRecord;
           [self.myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
           [self.pendingOperations.downloadsInProgress removeObjectForKey:indexPath];
    }
```

This is the cellforwoeatindexpath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"HorizontalCell";
    HorizontalTableCell *cell = [self.myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[HorizontalTableCell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width)];
    }

cell.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/-2);

PictureRecord *aRecord = [self.photos objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

[cell.indicator startAnimating];
if (aRecord.hasImage) {
    [cell.indicator stopAnimating];
    [cell.pic setImage:aRecord.image];
    [cell setNeedsDisplay];
    cell.username.text = aRecord.username;
}
else if (aRecord.isFailed)  {
    [cell.indicator stopAnimating];
    cell.pic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"];
}
else {
    [cell.indicator startAnimating];
    if (!myTableView.dragging && !myTableView.decelerating) {
        [self startOperationsForPhotoRecord:aRecord atIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}

return cell;
}
```

Thanks

UPDATE:

One more information about this problem. After troubleshooting I found that the problem is with reloadRowsAtIndexPaths. It does not call cellForRowAtIndexPath for the image to load. However I'm still not sure it does not call cellForRowAtIndexPath. I have also tried [tableview reloadData] and no luck.

FIXED IT:
The problem was fixed by adding another tableview inside this existing table view. The way I had before was a UITableView inside a UIView. I modified it so I had one UITableView with one cell. Created a custom cell and added another table in that cell so I could scroll it horizontally and added another custom cell for the horizontal tableview with the imageview. That did the trick.